# Graph API search limit (graph_post_search_get)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search, post, graph, get

I use batch requests to search public posts.
I started twice a batch that performs 20 searches with different tokens, and I get this error:

(# 613) Calls to graph_post_search_get Have exceeded the rate of 10,000 calls per 1 second.

However, I am far from 10,000 calls per second! I have done no more than 40 searches in two batches (6 seconds).

I searched for information about this error, but I found nothing.
What is this "10,000 calls per 1 second?" A typo? What is the exact limit requests for research posts?
Is this a limit per token, or an overall limit to the application?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?  I'm receiving the error "Calls to graph_place_search_get have exceeded the rate of 10000 calls per 1 seconds" with no where near to 10,000 search calls being made.